# Fix CORS violation on MS edge (not cross domain) Request had a target IP address space of `unknown`

Tags: php, jquery, dns, cors, private-network-access

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.MYWEBSITE.com.au//COMPANY-supplier/include/includes/common/auto-people.php?term=a&clid=12345678' from origin 'https://www.MYWEBSITE.com.au' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request had a target IP address space of `unknown` yet the resource is in address space `public`.

I am getting this error when doing a simple `POST` request using jQuery (3.6.0). I'm unsure how to solve this. There are no other domains involved. The upload payload has a dataUrl collected from a file input tag and some ids. Other jQuery AJAX requests seem ok. This problem is intermittent (1 in 10 time) and doesn't happen every time. If someone (smarter than I) can suggest how to include a header that changes the address space to 'public', this may solve the problem.

A good starting point to answer this question comes from:-
[Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)
But the answers considered here don't address this particular problem.

I have ensured that:-
All content (including any third party libraries, are served from my server. (jquery etc).
All browser extensions are turned off.

Comment: Your URL has a second double-slash after `www.MYWEBSITE.com.au`, is this really intended?

Comment: No just a typo for this entry on stack overflow -  my apologies